# Linq to dataset - Sum method - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am getting the error of "Specified cast is not valid" for this statement. The field present at index 3 is float based in the datatable (coming from the db). I tried even by replacing Decimal with int and float. It didn't work

dtData is a datatable obj.

```
var aggrVal = dtData.AsEnumerable().Sum(k => k.Field<Decimal>(3));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you try to check what is actual data type of the column: dtData.Columns[3].DataType

Comment: the debugging the problem by converting your data to List (dtData.ToList()) and iterate though it using for/foreach loop. Then see how the problematic data looks like. My guess is that your field is nullable and you need to cast to 'Decimal?'

Comment: The datatype came out to be Double. I guess i need to cast it to integer.

Comment: It worked with Double !!

Answer (score 0):

```
var aggrVal = dtData.AsEnumerable().Sum(k => k.Field<Decimal>(3));
```

changed to

```
var aggrVal = dtData.AsEnumerable().Sum(k => k.Field<Double>(3));
```

made it work. The data type for the column is float (sql side), but on the .NET it needs to be matched with Double.